QGIS crashes when the script runs
I'm writing a script on PyQGIS, but when I start it, this always crashes and I don't understand the reason.
After a lot of attempts, I undersand the problems are the following rows of code:
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([aRispettoLayer])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([edF])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([terrF])


Are there alternative instructions that do the same task? Is there someone with the same problem?


Can you add the part of the code that cause the crash to your question

I can, but the script Is very long and I don't know which part could make to crash. However then I will edit the message with the script.
